# Using window.open() or a hyperlink with a _target attribute, is it possible to force a link to open in a new window rather than a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html

Or is that strictly dependent on the web browser's settings?

Answer (score 2):

No. Right now, browsers don't distinguish between tabs and windows in their JavaScript APIs.